# Converting fragmented mp4 file for MSE (Media Source Extensions)

Tags: javascript, avconv, mse

I'm looking for a way to generate proper fragmented *.mp4 files for [MediaSourceExtension](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html) (Chrome).

I tried out the example from here: http://people.mozilla.org/~jyavenard/tests/mse_mp4/paper.html and with the given video file it worked just fine.

So I tried out some settings for avconv / MP4 box to get my own video files working, but I'm just getting video errors...

```
avconv -i file -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov  output.mp4

MP4Box -rap -frag-rap -dash 30000 -segment-name out.mp4 output.mp4
```

Chrome media-internals says: error Skipping unrecognized top-level box: ftyp

So does anyone know how to convert them properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this MP4Box command:

```
mp4box -dash 5000 -frag 5000 -rap input.mp4
```